# Split a String at space, but only outside of quotes

Tags: java, regex, string

i would like to split a String at every space character, but split the quoted parts out seperately.
I tried using the regex pattern

```
",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"
```

and replaced the `commas ","` with `space " " or "\\s"`

```
"\\s(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"
```

and it works fine in the following example: 
Input: `"foo \"bar foo\" bar"` 
Output:`[foo, "bar foo", bar]`

but if you remove the space before and after the inner quotes, you get the following: 
Input: `"bar foo\"bar foo\"bar foo"` 
Output: `["bar", "foo\"bar foo\"bar", "foo"]`
Desired Output: `["bar", "foo", "\"bar foo\"", "bar", "foo"]`

@the-fourth-bird kindly created the following regex

```
"(?:\\h|(?=\")|(?<=\"))(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"
```

which works in the above situation, but fails in the case of spaces:
Input: `"foo \"bar foo\" bar"`
Output: `["foo", "", "\"bar foo\"", "bar"]`
Desired Output: `["food", "\"bar foo\"", "bar"]`

This problem can be solved by just removing empty strings from the array, but is there also a way to solve it in the regex?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Please give a more thorough example and expected output. For example, your title talks about spaces within quotes and outside quotes, but your current sample does not have both of these cases.

Comment: You might try it with lookarounds, but this behaviour can be error prone with unbalanced double quotes `(?:\h|(?=")|(?<="))(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)` https://regex101.com/r/otbMEQ/1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that is simple and works for my case:

```
    /[^"\s]+|"[^"]*"/
```